# Prove extrema is global minima by showing there is no global maxima?

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

I came across the following problem:

> Find the smallest value of $x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2 + x_4^2$ where $x_1 - x_2 + 2x_3 - x_4 = 1$.

Setting $g(x) = x_1 - x_2 + 2x_3 - x_4 - 1$ and using Lagrange multipliers $(\nabla f) = \lambda(\nabla g)$ you can easily find $f(1/7, -1/7, 2/7, -1/7) = 1/7$ to be a local extrema.

For the final step which is proving that this point is in fact a global minimum, the solution provided by my professor states that:

> Since $f$ can assume arbitrarily large values, for example along the line $x = (1 + t, t, 0, 0)$ as $t \rightarrow \infty$ and is non-negative, our candidate is a minimum value.

I understand this proves that the point cannot be a global maxima. However I must humbly ask: Is this sufficient proof that this point is a global minima?

(i) How can we know that it is not a local maxima?

(ii) How can we know that the function can't assume arbitrarily small values elsewhere? $f$ is non-negative and has no other extrema, however can I be sure there is no limit where $f$ tends to a smaller value than $1/7$, without further investigation?

Comment: Have a look at bordered Hessian https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix

Comment: Your question (i) is easy - you just need to do use the second derivative test. The question (ii) takes some tinkering and it's specific to the problem, but this one is easy because if one of the $x_i$ goes to infinity, regardless of which, your function diverge to infinity. So you can be rest assured there won't be any minima coming from some type of "infinite"  boundary.

Answer (score 1):

This particular case can be solved by direct substitution so defining

$$
f(x_1,x_2,x_3) = x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+(x_1-x_2+2x_3-1)^2
$$

and calculating the Hessian at the stationary point $X^* = (\frac 17,-\frac 17, \frac 27)$ we have

$$
H(X^*) = \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 4 & -2 & 4 \\
 -2 & 4 & -4 \\
 4 & -4 & 10 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

which is positive definite so the found stationary point is a local minimum.

Comment: So then, would it be correct to say that the statement provided in the solution alone is not sufficient proof that this point is the global minima, as you would need to investigate the point further using, for example, the Hessian?

Comment: The Lagrange multipliers technique furnishes the so called stationary points. After that, a convenient point qualification is needed. As an example, the solution of the Lagrangian depicted in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4664227/fx-y-z-with-both-leq-and-constraints-general-questions/4664806#4664806 gives minimum, saddle and maximum points.